# Getting current build number in jenkins using python

Tags: python, jenkins, jobs, jenkins-api

I have a python script from which I am trying to get the current build number of a job in jenkins. Below script gives the last build number and whether the build is success or failure. How can I get the current build number? I mean when I run this script, It will build with new build number and how can I get that current build number?

script.py

```
import jenkins
import urllib2 
import urllib
import sys

j = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080')
if not j.job_exists('sample1234'):
    j.create_job('sample1234', jenkins.EMPTY_CONFIG_XML)

j.reconfig_job('sample1234', jenkins.RECONFIG_XML)
j.build_job('sample1234')

last_build_number = j.get_job_info('sample123')['lastCompletedBuild'] ['number']
print last_build_number

build_info=j.get_build_info('sample123',last_build_number)
if build_info['result']=='SUCCESS':
    print "Build Success "
else:
    print " Build Failed "
```

Comment: The dirty answer is to do `last_build_number + 1`. I would print `j.get_job_info('sample123')` to see if it has a "currentBuild" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for is within the python-jenkins [documentation](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) specifically at Example 9

The code snippet below is from their documentation:

```
next_bn = server.get_job_info('job_name')['nextBuildNumber']
server.set_next_build_number('job_name', next_bn + 50)
```

I think you really only need the first line for the current/next build number. The caveat is that you need this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin) for your jenkins.