# How to get failure causes of current build in Jenkins using Python?

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to implement currentbuild.rawbuild.getcauses() in Python. How can I do that? The functn is presently a part of groovy script which needs to be converted to Python.

I don't seem to find anything for it. The below link is closest to what I could find :

[Getting current build number in jenkins using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40097012/getting-current-build-number-in-jenkins-using-python)

Comment: your question sounds incorrect because groovy is a native language for jenkins and python is not. you can call python from jenkins and pass the parameters into it including getcauses. please edit your question and add more details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am looking for a workaround to implement that in python

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python API for Jenkins:

```
http://my-jenkins/job/my-job/my-build-number/api/python
```

This will include information about the build, including the build cause(s). From the main api page http://my-jenkins/job/my-job/my-build-number/api:

> ###### Python API
>
> Access the same data as Python for Python clients. This can be parsed into Python objects as
> `ast.literal_eval(urllib.urlopen("...").read())` and the resulting
> object tree is identical to that of JSON.

Example of returned data (excerpt):

```
{
  "_class" : "hudson.model.CauseAction",
  "causes" : [
    {
      "_class" : "hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause",
      "shortDescription" : "Started by upstream project \"my_upstream_build\" build number 123",
      "upstreamBuild" : 123,
      "upstreamProject" : "my_upstream_build",
      "upstreamUrl" : "job/my_upstream_build/"
    }
  ]
},
```